# Disconnect and unsubscribe Action Cable on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-6

This was already asked here, but it seems that the old methods ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495351/how-to-close-connection-in-action-cable) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765963/detect-unsubscribe-from-action-cable-on-page-change)) no longer work on Rails 6 because you cannot use `App.channel` inside your `app/javascript/channels/your_channel.js`.
Though, correct me if I'm wrong because I'm new to Rails.

My question is: how to disconnect or/and unsubscribe from client side on Rails 6?

I'm especially interested in the "on page change" scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you shared with us, I imagine you are trying to remove a subscription. You can remove it using `consumer.subscriptions.remove` [[1]](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/javascript/action_cable/subscriptions.js#L36).

Could you share the snippet of code you have in your `app/javascript/channels/your_channel.js`?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to save the subscription on a `this` variable and do the remove call if this variable is not null when page loads, then do the new subscription.

```
// File: app/javascript/channels/your_channel.js
import consumer from "./consumer";

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    if (this.subscription) {
        consumer.subscriptions.remove(this.subscription);
        console.log("unsubing");
    }

    if ($('#hashtag').attr('data-hashtag-id')) {
        var subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: "TweetsChannel", id: $('#hashtag').attr('data-hashtag-id')}, {
            connected() {
                console.log("we are live on: " + $('#hashtag').attr('data-hashtag-id'));
            },

            disconnected() {
                console.log("disconecting")
            },

            received(data) {
                $('#tweets-card').prepend(data.content)
            }
        });

        this.subscription = subscription;
    }
});
```